# Java tree hierarchy

Tags: java, directory, hierarchy

I've (as a Java beginner) got the following problem. I want to Display the Tree hierarchy from a directory (same or kind of the same you can do with windows CMD with: tree C:/)

hope for quick response

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole File System hierarchy using [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles())

Comment: This is true, but slightly misleading: you can get the files in a directory using `File.listFiles()`, and you can call `listFiles` on those files recursively; but you don't automatically get the full hierarchy simply by calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

The `listFiles()` method in `java.io.File` lists the files in a directory. Starting from there, you can go through the directory tree recursively:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    listDirectory(new File("C:/"), 0);
}

private static void listDirectory(File directory, int level)
{
    for(File file : directory.listFiles())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            System.out.print('\t');
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        if(file.isDirectory())
            listDirectory(file, level + 1);
    }
}
```